# Is this question no longer 'too broad'

Tags: discussion, questions

I have edited my question [How did prisoners of war discover scientific breakthroughs while interned?](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/322/what-are-some-scientific-breakthroughs-made-by-interned-prisoners-of-war), which currently has 3 close votes as being 'too broad'.

The question now focuses on **how** scientists (and mathematicians) were able to make their discoveries while interned.  This keeps the answers as still valid, while not asking for a list, but asking for techniques (similar to many other questions)

Comment: It is now at 4 close votes

Comment: I only see 3 up 3 down in my review. It's probably not be showing me the initiating vote.

Comment: @J.W.Perry I hope the edit makes it less broad

Comment: Looks fine to me, and it garnered particular answers not broad ones. We shall see I suppose.

Comment: I am hoping that if it is good now, the close votes would be retracted

Comment: I was just researching how that works. As in, how do the leave open versus close votes interact with each other. My [current read](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139834/what-exactly-happens-with-the-button-leave-open-previously-do-not-close).

Comment: I have retracted a close vote before, all I did was to click the 'close' button and then there was a button to retract it. There is a caveat, it said that once a retraction is done, then you can't re-vote to close on that question.

Comment: Indeed. In this case, from what I read, a couple more well timed leave open votes will cause the whole issue to just go away more quickly. The details behind this are not made clear to us.